# Wrong position of elements when used with display-block

Tags: html, css, attributes

I have the following HTML/CSS documents:

HTML:

```
<div class="test" >
    <a>a</a>
    <div></div>
    <a >a</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
    border: 2px solid;
    font-size: 0;
}

.test > * {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

All 3 children are displayed as "inline-block". If all children have content everything is OK.

**But if any of those 3 children have no content, then vertical alignment is totally wrong.**

Look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ClementVidal/mb7wzy30/5/

Does any body know why this happen and for which reason ?

*Note: I'm using Chrome 40.*

Comment: Looks good to me, they align to baseline which is the default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)
>
> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

Therefore you need to change the `vertical-align` property of the `inline-block` elements.

As stated above, the default value for the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. When the sibling elements contain text, they are aligned to the baseline. By changing the `vertical-align` property value to something like `top`, the text will no longer be aligned to the base of the middle element.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/d6pv8xd5/)

```
.test > * {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always set the vertical alignment manually:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```